# Apply np.random.rand to groups - optimization issue

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

Need to optimize a single line of code that will be executed tens of thousands of times during the calculations and hence timing becomes an issue. Seems to be simple but really got stuck.

The line is:

```
df['Random']=df['column'].groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: np.random.rand())
```

So I want to assign the same random number to each group and "ungroup". Since rand() is called many times using this implementation the code is very ineffective.

Can someone help in vectorizing this?

Comment: If you want to assign random number why do you need groupby? You can directly use `np.random.rand` to fill that `Random` column.

Comment: One way is to select unique values in df['column'], create a new column in this df and then join with the initial data frame. But there must exist more elegant solution.

Comment: Need groupby() to make sure the SAME random number is assigned to each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.random.randint(2,5,50)),columns=['column'])
uniques =df['column'].unique()
final = df.merge(pd.Series(np.random.rand(len(uniques)),index=uniques).to_frame(),
                 left_on='column',right_index=True)
```

You can store the `uniques` and then run last line every time to get new random numbers and join with df.

Comment: That will work, indeed! Need to replace right_on with right_index=True. Still in case of many groups in the data the join operation can take significant amount of time. Wonder if there is a one-liner to do this.